# How to have an object maintained for each HTTP request, in a thread-safe manner?

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading

My page code sets values in Session and other HTTPContext.current items. These values are used in other class files, which exists under App Code.

In order to implement threading for some of the features, i need to remove the use of the HTTPContext in the other class files (which will probably become separate assemblies later). To communicate the values between the page code and the other objects in a thread safe manner, I tried,

a) Passing the current HTTPContext as an object to new thread - fails because the reference in the new thread is destroyed along with the primary object.

b) Static class & members - problem is that they are not different for each request. Throughout the app, they are same.

c) We could create a simple class with public members, whose values will be set on the page and the object has to be passed along the code whenever needed. The problem here is that, then, i have to have code changes throughout the app, to pass the object along, with each function.

d) Heard about Singleton - it looks like this is a stretch and not the right answer.

Basically, i'm looking for a standard practice that could let me set values to a class members which is maintained uniquely for each request, which can be passed to new thread. Any pointers to help achieve this on .net?

Comment: In most cases "I'll add more threads" is an anti-pattern in an ASP.Net situation. The server's already created and is using a whole load of threads - to service other requests. What's the *specific* use case here that you think warrants creating more threads for?

Comment: I have some "Fire and Forget" routines to do. Example: Saving audit log records during an action on the app. At the max, i might end up having two more threads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is possible, you definitely should go with C approach and pass data to methods and threads explicitly via arguments. The code would be more explicit. If it is not possible you can use something like this:

```
public SomeClass{
    public static ConcurrentDictionary<Thread, HttpContextData> HttpContextData 
        = new ConcurrentDictionary<Thread, HttpContextData>();
}

// class to hold HttpContext related data
class HttpContextData { ... }


// somewhere in Asp.Net app...
ThreadStart fireAndForgetFunc = () =>
{
    var data = SomeClass.HttpContextData.GetValueOrDefault(Thread.CurrentThread);
    // work with HttpContextData
};

fireAndForgetFunc += () => 
{  
    // adding a cleanup
    SomeClass.HttpContextData.TryRemove(Thread.CurrentThread, out HttpContextData data); 
};
Thread t = new Thread(fireAndForgetFunc);

var httpContextData = new HttpContextData() {};
SomeClass.HttpContextData.TryAdd(t, httpContextData);
t.Start();
```

But you should bear in mind:

1. this code is kinda tricky and should be used only as a workaround
2. The cleanup won't be executed if the thread is aborted or throws an
   exception
3. HttpContextData can be accessed from more than one thread. In this case you need aware about thread-safety.

**Answer to the questions int the comment**

`ConcurrentDictionary` is like usual dictionary, but it is thread safe and can be used in a multithreading environment without any locks.

Yes, dictionary will be shared throughout the app, but each entry in the dictionary will be related to the certain `thread` with `HttpContextData` assigned to it during http-request processing somewhere in asp.net code.

> Since the context data is moved to a separate object, it will call for code changes throughout the code tree under the "Fire and Forget" functions.

it will call only changes like below. Changing this:

```
var data = HTTPContext.Current.GetSomeData();
```

to:

```
var data = _httpContextData.GetValueOrDefault(Thread.CurrentThread);
```

Comment: Thank you. Meanwhile, do you think the below pose any challenges?

1. Since the context data is moved to a separate object, it will call for code changes throughout the code tree under the "Fire and Forget" functions. _italic_(Point c in my question above)_italic_.

2. Since the  ConcurrentDictionary is declared static, wondering there may be a possibility that the values will be shared throughout the app. My objective is to have the values uniquely maintained per request. _italic_(related to Point b)_italic_

ConcurrentDictionary is new to me. Will implement to see how this goes.

Comment: Appreciate the quick answers. Will go ahead and post the results.

Comment: Class1 has static CD. Class2 represents the HttpContextData. Class3 has the threadcode. In Class3, there is no reference for _httpContextData. Probably i'm declaring the static CD in the wrong place. Probably, it should be Class1._httpContextData with the Class1 also as static?

Comment: why In Class3, there is no reference for _httpContextData? maybe _httpContextData is not public. Btw, I added `public` keyword to the answer. Only CD should be static

Comment: _httpContextData is public in Class1. Class3 don't have a direct reference in that scenario. Class1._httpContextData is becoming necessary.

Comment: Your answer helped. Thank you. Marked as answer. Trying to figure out how this might work with QueueBackgroundWorkItem. Will take it from here.